# How to pass a formatted query to findOne() in mongo using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've one Restful service developed using node.js which takes some values from a user. According to the values given it reformats a query string. But, Whenever I want to pass this query to findone() of mongoDB and calls that service it showing "query selector must be an object" message on browser.

```
var query = "{" ;
if( orderNo == " "){
        // Don't append anything
}else{
        query = query + "'orderNo' : " + orderNo ;
}
.
.
.
query = query + "}";
```

And, I also tried like below :

```
var query = {};
query[orderNo] = orderNo;

db.collection('*****').findOne(query, function(err, item) {
     console.log(item);
     res.jsonp(item);
});
```

In both cases I'm getting the same result in browser.
Anyone guide me how I can query these kind of queries in MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there on your second attempt. When you do this

```
var query = {};
query[orderNo] = orderNo;
```

you create an object with key name the same as the value! For example, if the value of `orderNo` is 12345, then the above statement will produce the object

```
query = {
    "12345": 12345
}
```

You could use the same **[bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)** to create a proper query **[object property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)**

```
query = { 
    "orderNo": 12345 
}
```

as follows:

```
var query = {};
if(orderNo != " ") query["orderNo"] = orderNo; 

db.collection('*****').findOne(query, function(err, item) {
     console.log(item);
     res.jsonp(item);
});
```